# Windows is writing to the physical end of my disk

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, defragment

I have a secondary hard drive that I keep all my games and non important data on. I am constantly saving and deleting items off of this drive. Lately I noticed performance degradation on the drive, similar to when a drive is physically full. I took a look at the drive since it wasn't even 50% full and found something like this. [image: disk layout.]

It was actually a lot worse before but I defragged my drive and this fixed the problem. Now that the issue is coming again I checked again and saw the same thing. I always thought real time defrag from products like Diskeeper were a gimmick but is that something I need right now? Or is there another issue?

I have another drive that does not behave like this.

Comment: Look --> at the "Related" questions and start reading. All will be revealed.

Comment: @DavidPostill I read them all and didn't find any relevant to my scenario. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

If a sector gets marked as bad, by something like SCNDSK, it will not write to that sector again. It will attempt to read the data from a bad sector and move it to a more reliable sector. The bad sector is then put into a bad sector table that disables writing to that sector again.

By the looks of it, your disk is failing pretty bad.

Comment: I have run chkdsk /r the last time this happened and found nothing. I will run it again to be safe though.

Comment: **`chkdsk` only checks the file system on the disk.**

Comment: @Ramhound `chkdsk /R` also "*locates bad sectors and recovers readable information*".

Comment: My research says otherwise [**"chkdsk utility checks the file system and file system metadata of a volume (hard drive) for logical and physical errors.  When called with /r parameter it locates physical disk errors in the file system and attempts to recover data from any affected disk sectors."**](http://www.bing.com/search?q=chkdsk+%2Fr&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=chkdsk+&sc=8-7&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=257082DBDC0F484E97EBE856CB5C2F68).  Its a file system tool.  It won't mark sectors on the drive bad or good though.

Comment: @Ramhound, dxiv is correct. chkdsk /r does report and mark sectors as bad. It would also be silly for a tool to scan through, move data from bad sectors, and not mark them. That would just allow data to write to the already known bad sectors again. Since you don't believe that it doesn't mark bad sectors, because it doesn't explicitly say it, I dug into [old documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chkdsk.mspx?mfr=true). It's under the "Reporting bad disk sectors" section.

Comment: @DrZoo - I know `chkdsk` receivd new functionality with Windows 8+ I seem to recall that `chkdsk` was primarly a file system tool but see that /r is from Windows XP.  So who knows what I was thinking.

Comment: Ok good to know, I have rerun the tool again and not found a single error.

Comment: @Chris I'm not fully sure how the scan works once the sectors have already been marked. You can run chkdsk with the /b argument. This clears the list of bad clusters and rescans the entire disk. /b also includes the same functionality as /r. So instead of of having to run `chkdsk /b /r` you can just do `chkdsk /b`. This should then list the errors.